# getting javascript error while iterating through array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function sortproducts(filprodlist)
{
    var prod;
    var k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < filprodlist.length; i++) {
        var k = i + 1;
        var p=filprodlist[i].EntityKey.substr(filprodlist[i].EntityKey.length - 1);
        var p2=filprodlist[k].EntityKey.substr(filprodlist[k].EntityKey.length - 1);
        if ( p>p2)  {
            temp = filprodlist[k];
            filprodlist[k] = filprodlist[i];
            filprodlist[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    rederProduct(filprodlist);
}
```

while executing above code getting following error
TypeError: filprodlist[k] is undefined

Comment: it's answer is in other part of your code, show it

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in `sort` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `var` inside loops, blocks don't have scope in *JavaScript*, `var` every variable you want to use in one `var` statement. End your loop when the highest index reaches the end (`k`). You can move `k` into the `for`'s iterate step because you're really iterating with this, too.

```
function sortproducts(filprodlist) {
    var prod, i, k, p, p2, temp;
    for (i = 0, k = 1; k < filprodlist.length; ++i, ++k) {
        p =  filprodlist[i].EntityKey.substr(filprodlist[i].EntityKey.length - 1);
        p2 = filprodlist[k].EntityKey.substr(filprodlist[k].EntityKey.length - 1);
        if (p > p2)  {
            temp = filprodlist[k];
            filprodlist[k] = filprodlist[i];
            filprodlist[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    rederProduct(filprodlist);
}
```

A different way to do it is forget `k` all together, start from `i = 1` and use `i - 1`  and `i`, this means you're iterating with less variables so it might be easier for you to follow the code in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

*Reason*

On last iteration, when `i` is at last element of array. You are fetching are using `var k = i + 1;`, where `k` doesn't exists. Thus you are getting the error.

So Use

```
for (i = 0; i < filprodlist.length - 1; i++) {
```

instead of

```
for (i = 0; i < filprodlist.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `filprodlist` has 10 items. Then the items are indexed 0-9 and Your `i` goes through 0-9. In every iteration You define `k = i + 1`. So in the last iteration `i = 9`, `k = 10` and You are trying to access `filprodlist[10]` which doesn't exist (returns `undefined`). Solution is in @Satpal's answer.